# need help solving - system of equations

Tags: matrices

i was writing a model paper for a olympiad when i encountered this question:
i thought of using cramer's rule or just proceed with matrix inversion method but i am stuck trying to figure it out. is there any possible to find the answer?

Consider a system of equations:

$A_1 x+B_1y+C_1 = L$

$A_2 x+B_2y+C_2 = M$

$A_3x+B_3y+C_3 = N$

given L+M+N = 0 what kind of solutions will the above system of equations have ?

Answer (score 1):

If $L+M+N = 0$ then we would have $(A_1+A_2+A_3)x + (B_1+B_2 + B_3)y + (C_1 + C_2 + C_3) = 0 $ by adding all your equations. This is the equation for the line
$$ y = -\frac{C_1 + C_2 + C_3}{B_1+B_2 + B_3} - \frac{A_1+A_2+A_3}{B_1+B_2 + B_3}x.$$
So any solution to your equations will be on this line.

Comment: so you are saying that the system has infinitely many solutions ?

Comment: No, that depends on the value of you coefficients $A_i$ and $B_j$. Your system has $3$ equations with $2$ unknowns and in general such systems does not have any solutions (unless the equations are linearly dependent). If all equations are linearly dependent, then you would have infinitely many solutions. However, if there is a solution then it would be on the line.